# Wordpress - Woocommerce Users Registragion / Management

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-permissions

a client just asked me to create an e-shop digital market, and he gave me some instructions about users. Since i am new to wordpress, i am trying to figure out which plugins to use for these requirements. 
So the client needs :

- Import from a file pre-registered users with default password ( so when they come to the website , they will reset their password with their own )
- Users Levels ( for example, Gold Members, Silver Members, e.t.c )
- Restricted Areas ( by user level )

Which plug-ins you are suggesting, or how to manage this ?

The e-shop will use WooCommerce , OceanWP theme with some addons.

Thank you in advance. 
John